# Chrome и адаптивная верстка

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, google-chrome, адаптивная-верстка

Полчаса двигаю туда-сюда экран в панеле разработчика в браузере Chrome, не понимая почему не работает медиа-запрос. Потом закрыл панель разработчика и просто сжал окно браузера. Все заработало. Скажите, это я что-то не понимаю или у мне хром бракованый попался?
[image: Вид страницы из панели разработчика хром]

[image: Корректно работающий медиа-зпрос на сжатом окне]

Вот сам медиа-запрос

```
@media all and (max-width: 900px) {
  .header .col-1 {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 0;
  }
  .header .col-2 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался, надо было прописать

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```